# I don't see Custom Component in App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-apps, appexchange, flexipages

I installed a custom component (managed package) from AppExchange but I don't see it in App Builder for a App Page.

Can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot and searching for the [Lightning Tree component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EOCHnUAP) in appexchange led me to this [github source](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-tree/blob/master/src/aura/Tree/Tree.cmp) for the component

It seems to be an open source reusable component that you can include in your apps via code ([look at this sample](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-tree-sample/blob/master/src/aura/TreeSampleApp/TreeSampleApp.app)). but the component is not implementing any of the interfaces by default to enable it to be used in the app builder or lightning actions or community builder etc..

you can edit the component code in your org and make it implement the interface *flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes* for it to appear in the App builder..

you can go thru [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm) for details on how to enable components for App builder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, I understand that I create a my component and use Lightning Tree component as a child component.